# Installing lxml to a separate file

Tags: python, import, lxml

I'm building a python program for someone who is not tech savy, so I don't want to have to make them install a bunch of modules. Currently I am using BeautifulSoup, pdfkit, and lxml. I pulled the first two into a subdirectory that I can import from, but lxml is giving me trouble. Right now the modules are all dragged into a file called SupportingFiles, and all of the imports in the python files have been changed accordingly. The current issue is that it is throwing the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lupin/Desktop/WebToPDF/WebToPDF.py", line 14, in <module>
    import SupportingFiles.lxml.html
  File "/Users/Lupin/Desktop/WebToPDF/SupportingFiles/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from SupportingFiles.lxml import etree
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 84, in init lxml.etree (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:191834)
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Does anyone know how to fix this, or am I stuck telling them to import lxml themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try PyInstaller

[PyInstaller](http://pythonhosted.org//PyInstaller/) is the solution to go.

Try to build single execetable file, for simplest programs it has size about 4.1 MB on my Ubuntu,but with more code it will not grow so much, as initial file has to contain complete Python.